# Calling WCF method inside a Transaction cause error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, entity-framework-6, transactionscope

I have a complex application and encountered an error. I simplified my real problem with the following code.

I have a WCF Service with a method that performs a select on one of my tables:

```
public string FindDocumentNumber(int documentId)
{
    using(var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
       return context.Documents.Where(x=>x.Id == documentId && x.Tag == "*")
                               .Select(x=>x.Number).FirstOrDefault();
    }   
}
```

In my Console application I have following code:

```
using(var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using(var context = new MyDbContext())   
    {
        var doc = context.Documents.Where(x=>x.Id == 12345).FirstOrDefault();
        doc.Tag = "*";
        context.SaveChange();
    }

    ... 
    var number = myWCFService.FindDocumentNumber(12345); // At this point, I encounter an error
    ...
    //some other updates on document with Id = 12345 
    scope.Complete();
}
```

However, when running the code, I encounter the following error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException
> HResult=0x8013193C   Message=An error occurred while executing the
> command definition. See the inner exception for details.
> Source=   StackTrace:
>
> Inner Exception 1: SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The
> timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the
> server is not responding.
>
> Inner Exception 2: Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

Where is the problem?

Comment: Why are you using TransactionScope in the first place? A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work already. It doesn't need external transactions. *All* tracked changes are saved in a single interal database transaction when you call `SaveChanges` or discarded if the DbContext is disposed. Remove `TransactionScope` and call `SaveChanges` only when you want to finalized all changes

Comment: WCF supports the WS-Transactions standard, so when you used the TransactionScope you automatically enrolled both the WCF call and EF Core's internal transaction into the same distributed transaction. If the WCF connection takes too long the overall transaction can timeout. If you open multiple connections inside the same scope all of them will become part of the same distributed transaction and could easily block each other. If you use multiple DbContexts inside the scope instead of a single one, you run the same risk as the internal connections will be rolled into the transaction

Comment: What does the rest of the code look like and why is an explicit transaction used? It's almost certainly possible to rewrite the code to avoid blocks and timeouts

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I simplified my real problem with this question, I used `TransactionScope` because I need to update data after calling WCF service. Another thing that I am using EF and not EF Core.

Comment: Make the call to `SaveChanges` after the call then. It doesn't matter what ORM you use. The DbContext/Session (in NHibernate) is a Unit-of-Work that keeps all pending changes in memory and stores all of them at once.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I Updeted the question, My WCF Service has its own `DbContext `an I need the updated record in my WCF Service, so I can not call `SaveChange()` after the call.

Comment: I still don't see any reason to use `TransactionScope`. That only *creates* problems. In this case it locks the record that the service is trying to load, resulting in a block. Had you just called `SaveChanges` there would be no problem. That's no different than using 2 connections and trying any of the examples that show how transactions block each other. The Console connection locks the record with an Exclusive lock while the service tries to read the same row, waiting until the console completes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I use the `TransactionScope` due to the need for updating the document before and after calling the WCF service.

Comment: `due to the need for updating the document` that's not true. Why do you think you need a TransactionScope for that at all? You simply *don't*. `SaveChanges` saves all pending changes already.   A DbContext isn't a database connection. In fact, it wouldn't even keep a connection open if you hadn't forced it to do so with TransactionScope. If you *don't* dispose the DbContext you'll be able to modify `doc` after the WCF call and call `SaveChanges` again. The *new* changes would be persisted. And if you didn't want them, you could just exit without calling `SaveChanges`

Comment: Why don't you try to remove `TransactionScope`, widen the scope of `context` to cover the entire method and just let EF work? You'll find that the changes are persisted without problems.

Comment: `I need the Tag field value` I understand what the code does. I'm saying the code is broken. Trying to explain that you want to save the Tag doesn't change the fact that using `TransactionScope` is a bug. I even explained how it blocks the service because it takes an Exclusive lock on the table row, while another connection is trying to read it. That's the *classic* blocking example shown in database tutorials and courses

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I said " I simplified my real problem". In my real application, The document update part that used before and after `WCF` call, are in separate methods (I dont use `DbContext` Injection, so each method has its own `DBContext`, so I can not call one `SaveChange()` for two methods) I have to use `TransactionScope`

Comment: `so each method has its own DBContext` that's the critical bug that breaks EF's transaction behavior. After breaking it, you added `TransactionScope` to get back the same behavior and found out you're blocking other connections. That's a very well know *bad* practice. Try using EF properly instead, the way it's shown in all tutorials. Use one DbContext instance for the entire operation. Modify the objects, don't try to perform CRUD operations. Call `SaveChanges` at the end and let *EF* generate the CUD operations

Comment: The bad pattern forced a long-lived connection where none would be used. By itself, EF doesn't even use a connection until it has to either load new data or persist changes. This way blocking is reduced dramatically, resulting in 10-100x better throughput. That's how ADO.NET itself works since 2001, and VB6 since the late 1990s. By starting a transaction you force ADO.NET to keep transactions open even after a DbContext is disposed. You can't have a transaction in a *closed* connection after all. And by using multiple DbContexts, the code opens *multiple* connections instead of reusing one

Comment: @Masoud: You don't need to use **TransactionScope** because your code is sequentially written and it is not performing any asyncronous operation: your tag will be persisted before your WCF call. If you are in a multiuser environment, use Optimistic Concurrency instead. Perhaps someone else is incorretly locking your table. Forget the locks and the transactions: EF will handle them for you.

Comment: @FabioCaruso TransactionScope has nothing to do with async vs sync or sequential vs parallel. It's not just that a DbContext isn't meant to be used in parallel, it's the entirely wrong tool to use if you want to perform a large bulk operation. As for the locks, it's the code in the question itself. The console is updating the row with `ID=12345` thus taking an Exclusive lock on it. The services is trying to read the same row and gets blocked. SSMS's Activity Monitor will show the two connections and that one is blocking the other.

Comment: @Masoud to see for yourself the effects of this code, open SSMS, open Activity Monitor and look at the blocked connections and what connection is blocking them. Inspect the SQL each one is trying to run. You'll see it's the code you posted here

Comment: @Masoud to emulate the same with just SQL, use whatever DBA IDE you like (SSMS, Azure Data Studio, DBeaver, anything) and open *two* tabs, ie two connections. Run `BEGIN TRAN; Update Documents Set Tag='*' where ID=12345;` in the first. In the second, just type `SELECT * from Documents Where ID=12345`. It's blocked, even without an explicit transaction because the *first* transaction is still active. Go to SSMS, Activity Monitor and inspect the two connections. You'll see one is blocking the other. You'll have to run `COMMIT TRAN` or `ROLLBACK TRAN` in the first tab.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: I tried Masoud's code and it's perfectly working, because the eventual lock to writing "Tag" is released **before** service finding operation (because it is a syncronous operation). Please, don't write useless 1000 characters answers...

Comment: In that case the question should be closed as non-reproducible. Unless you tried something else - using `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT` isolation instead of `READ COMMITTED` in which case the service will read the unmodified tag value. You already wrote several incorrect assertions regarding DbContext, WCF and TransactionScope. Don't assume others haven't worked with all these things in high-throughput systems for the last 25 years.

Comment: For example `is released before` - no it's not, because the transaction started with `var scope = new TransactionScope()` is still active. Locks are kept until the transaction is committed. It doesn't matter that DbContext is disposed. In fact all the CRUD classes that use DbContext as a connection *depend* on this to allow rolling back.

Comment: I badly explained myself: even if we agree that TransactionScope() should not be used, here the "Tag" is read and is seen as equal to "*" from the Find operation, because, also if not persisted to disk yet (due to transaction), in normal conditions it is in the ChangeTracker. The TIMEOUT exception propably depends from something else.

Comment: @FabioCaruso yes, the row-level X lock. No, it *has* been persisted, because `SaveChanges` was called. The row is still locked because there's an active transaction. `TransactionScope` doesn't affect the behavior of SaveChanges, it affects the SqlConnection itself.  I think you should check [Implementing an Implicit Transaction using Transaction Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/implementing-an-implicit-transaction-using-transaction-scope)

Comment: No. On my PC, on LocalDb, momentary stopping the code before the Find row, and reading datas from an external database client, the Tag "*" hasn't written yet. The following code "sees" the ChangeTracker value. While, without TransactionScope(), the "*" appears on the disk database.

Comment: I think it's something else that is locking, not this transaction.

Comment: If you want to maintain TransactionScope(), You can try to "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED", if anything else has not specified in database master.

Comment: @FabioCaruso that's terrible advice that's almost never needed or used in production. And can lead to corruption, missing or duplicate and random crashes. I strongly advise looking at [the possible consequences](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). Hacks like these are career limiting to put it mildly.

Comment: You think it is a serious risk, because in the past (from DBASEIII) we always have accustomed to think that: one locks and can modify the data, the others wait. But Microsoft's current orientation is not this: see articles about Optimistic Concurrency; "no more locks" they are saying...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are attempting to dispose the DbContext while inside a Transaction scope.  The Tx scope will want to ensure that changes to the DbContext and anything else that recognizes it will be committed at the same time, which will be blocking the `DbContext`.`Dispose` at the end of it's `using` block which is most likely the source of your exception.

If the API call is set up to work within a Tx Scope (which I suspect it isn't) then you would want to invert your `using` blocks to avoid that error:

```
using(var context = new MyDbContext())   
{
    using(var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        var doc = context.Documents.Where(x=>x.Id == 12345).Single();
        doc.Tag = "*";
        context.SaveChange();

        ... 
        var number = myWCFService.FindDocumentNumber(12345); // At this point, I encounter an error
        ...
        //some other updates on document with Id = 12345 
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

However, as the comments have said, the Tx Scope is likely not even necessary. The DbContext wraps its own transaction so if there is a condition where you don't want to commit the changes to the DB, just avoid calling `SaveChanges until you are satisfied everything should be committed.

```
using(var context = new MyDbContext())   
{
    var doc = context.Documents.Where(x=>x.Id == 12345).Single();
    doc.Tag = "*";

    ... 
    var number = myWCFService.FindDocumentNumber(12345); // At this point, I encounter an error
        ...
    //some other updates on document with Id = 12345 

    if (everythingIsOk) // Use a flag, check state, whatever....
        context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Transaction scopes are meant to coordinate multiple separate operations to ensure they all commit or roll back together. A common scenario where I see separate transactions used is when developers feel they need to save a record first, for instance to get a generated ID so they can use or set that ID somewhere else, but then still want the option to "back out" of that insert. There may be rare cases where this is a legitimate issue but more often than not it is just a limited implementation with better options to consider.